# iterating through rows sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need perform operations for all the enteries which have the same ID. My IDs go from 1 to 108. 
How would I write this in sql server 2012?

So far i tried:

```
select * 
into #ControlTable
from myOriginalTable

declare @ID int
while exists ( select * from #ControlTable)
begin 
select top 1 @ID = ID
from #ControlTable
order by ID asc, name, date

----code should go here, which is the syntax here, directly select * ... join on ...?
```

or should i try with a cursor?
something in the lines of:

```
select * 
    into #ControlTable
    from myOriginalTable

DECLARE @theCursor CURSOR;
DECLARE @ID int;
begin
   set @theCursor = CURSOR for
   select * from #ControlTable

   open @theCursor
   fetch next from @theCursor
   into @ID

   WHERE @@fetch_status = 0
begin
 -- again, not sure on how i need to write the syntax, i basically join two tables on a field
into @id
end;

close @theCursor;
deallocate @theCursor;
END;
```

**EDIT**:
What i want to actually do: Basically i just create a new temp table with an indexNumber so i can then join the data from the original table to the tempTable subtracting 249 positions and then i perform a calculation for this column called rate. That part I already done, but i have to do this for every of those 108 IDs.

**EDIT2**:

```
the part of the code mentioned at my first edit contains those selects:
select a, b, c, (index - 249) as indexNew
into #temp1
from originalTable
order by some criteria
```

then i am doing
something like:

```
 select t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, (t2.rate - t1.rate)* 100 as NewRate
into #anotherTemp
(
from 
   select * from #temp1
) t1
join 
(select * from #anotherTemp) t2
on t1.index = t2.indexNew
```

**EDIT 3**:

```
EXPECTED result.

    index col a     col b     col c  id rate   newRate

    take the rate index go up 249 positions calculate newRate using the formula   (t2.rate -t1.rate)*100 
, and do this for every id. 

    Once again, that part is working but only for one ID. I need to automate this. Thank you
```

**edit 4**: 
I really need help with this part:
after doing:

```
declare @ID int
while (select count (*) from #ControlTable) >0
begin
select top 1 @ID =ID from #ControlTable
```

-- now how do i put my selects which make that join here, only the format. Just directly write them, include brackets or?

Comment: Hi Virel, what you want to obtain, more explicit.   Salut Viorel, ce vrei tu sa faci de fapt ?? Ai doua tabele si ..

Comment: what are you trying to do? please add more details.

Comment: It all depends on what operations you are doing, you may not need to perform actions on a row by row basis and it's best to avoid this as it is horribly inefficient

Comment: I edited my question. If it's not enough I will explain it more, but that part i know how to do, the thing is, i have to do it for every ID.

Comment: add more details plz. looks like it my just be a select query with joins. add what you want to exactly do with sample data and expected resultset.

Comment: Can you post the sample data and expected result?

Comment: provide sample data, and stop thinking a Cursor is the solution here.

Comment: What dp you mean by 'go up 249 positions' do you mean in order of `ID asc, name, date`? What is t1 and t2 in `t2.rate -t1.rate`? Your question still makes no sense.

Comment: I cant post my real code, so i had to adjust. By going up 249 positions I mean have index number 1000. Go to index number 1000-249, take the value from the rate and use it in the calculation . that is not that important , I just want a solution on how to iterate trough 108 values and to have a (--your code goes here) part

Comment: i need help with my EDIT4, i think i can manage from there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @ID int
while (select count (*) from #ControlTable) >0
begin
select top 1 @ID =ID from #ControlTable

 (do something with your select here and when you are done)

delete from  #ControlTable where ID = @ID
end
```

This way you are going trough all of the rows and there is no chance of making a mistake and taking some row twice, if the data in #ControlTable should not be deleted, then copy everything from that table into another temp, and do the above with the second temp table.

Comment: thanks, I had an idea but was not sure quite how to do it.

Comment: Glad to help, thats why we are all here, i know the feeling. Cheers